# Como mudar pasta padrão de instalação do Composer?

Tags: php, composer

Existe alguma maneira de mudar o local onde o Composer instala as dependências?

O Composer sempre instala na pasta `vendor`, mas teria como alterar para uma outra pasta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro do `composer.json` do projeto ajuste o `config` -> `vendor-dir`, exemplo:

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "system/vendor"
},
```

No meu caso usei `system/vendor`

PS: creio que para os pacotes globais você possa setar a variável de ambiente `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR`:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-vendor-dir

Note que é possivel alterar o `vendor` via comando de linha usando:

```
COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=outro_diretorio
composer require pacote
```

Em Windows:

```
set COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=outro_diretorio
composer require pacote
```

Lembrando que isto só altera em tempo de execução e se tiver outros pacotes eles serão instalados novamente no novo diretório, então não vejo muitas vantagens em usar por usar, o uso da variável `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR` seria mais interessante se o `vendor` fosse controlado por outro ambiente ou programa, para gerar o nome ou local conforme alguma regra fosse necessária para descrever isto.

Um exemplo hipotético seria se você criasse um gerador de projetos (em CLI talvez) baseado em um projeto "template" em sua máquina, então os pacotes instalados deveriam ir sempre para o tal template e o teu "CLI" copiaria sempre do template na hora de enviar para produção, mas para desenvolvimento todos projetos usariam como base o template, seria uma das muitas prováveis ideias que isto poderia ser útil, aonde outro programa/ambiente controlaria o composer com `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR`.